# How to force windows 11 taskbar to hide again

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

I have Windows-11 set to auto-hide the Taskbar.

But sometimes it stays visible. Won't auto-hide. But, of course all other apps are now assuming it's going to autohide, so it obscures the bottom of all windows.
I am aware that explorer.exe process can get fouled, so restarting that might fix if it's "stuck" not autohiding. But there are also times that I just want it to autohide *faster*

Is there any way to force it back hidden?

Comment: Some people say it helps in *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > Taskbar behaviors* to uncheck "Show badges on the taskbar apps". Is yours checked?